# An inequality regarding calculus

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, radicals, maxima-minima

> Let $f:\mathbb{R_+} \times \mathbb{R_+}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $$f(x,y)=\frac{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}{x+y}$$ Prove that $$f(x,y) \geq \frac{8}{\sqrt{27}}, \: \forall x,y>0$$

The problem first suggests proving that $f(x,y)\geq f(\sqrt{y^2+1}-y,y)$, which I managed to do by straightforward substitution and also by derivatives. This led me to the inequality from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550756/determine-this-functions-minimum/2550776?noredirect=1#comment5265987_2550776), but I'm wondering if there is another approach, which maybe does not involve much calculus.

Comment: Have you tried the second derivative test? Of course this involves calculus, but it is usually the most straight-forward way to calculate maxs/mins.

Comment: I haven't considered it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve the System
$$y^2+2xy-1=0$$
$$x^2+2xy-1=0$$
this Comes from
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The function blows up to infinity if $x$ or $y$ get large, or if $x$ or $y$ approach $0$. Hence there is a minimizer in the interior of the orthant. Solving Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's equations give $x=y=1/\sqrt{3}$. Plugging this in the objective function gives the lower bound.